# Continuous linear line not showing in MPAndroidChart linechart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am making a linechart to show the number of cases of coronavirus in the world.

```
    private void setLinearChart() {
    lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    lineChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    lineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setTextSize(1f);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    lineChart.setVisibleXRange(100, 100);

    lineChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    lineChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMinimum(100);
    lineChart.setVisibleYRangeMinimum(100, 
    lineChart.getAxisLeft().getAxisDependency());


   caseslist = getCasesList(casesMap);


                LineDataSet casesSet = new LineDataSet(caseslist, "Cases");
                casesSet.setFillAlpha(110);

                LineData casesLineData = new LineData(casesSet);
                XAxis xAxis = lineChart.getXAxis();
                xAxis.setValueFormatter(new DateValueFormatter());
                lineChart.setData(casesLineData);
                lineChart.invalidate();

}
```

and I am getting a line char like this.[image: my linechart]

I this line to be a continuous curve like in below pic
[image: example image]

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1043#issuecomment-241662060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For smoother curve use

```
  casesSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
```